# WKHTMLTOPDF throwing Error Code 127

Tags: php, linux, shell, ftp, wkhtmltopdf

I recently re-uploaded all the source files of a web-application and WKHTMLTOPDF stopped working.

I was getting this error from the "bindings" (wkpdf.php):

WKPDF program error.
RESULT: 130
STDERR: 
STDOUT:

And after doing some research I found this possible solution:

https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=289

So, I changed FilleZilla's file transfer type to Binary and uploaded wkhtmltopdf-i386 again. However, now I get the following error when attempting to generate the PDF:

WKPDF program error.
RESULT: 127
STDERR: 
STDOUT:

The website's server is running on Linux and I do not have access to the shell (only to web files via FTP). Also, I have set all the proper permissions to the files.

What I don't understand is why it was working before but after over writing the files (with the exact same files) it stopped working.

Anyone has any idea how to get out of this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the issue: The bindings file was detecting the wrong CPU. I altered so it executes wkhtmltopdf-amd64 regardless of the detection and everything works fine now.